# Is it possible to extract some structured information from the Exception.StackTrace?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

I was wondering if it's possible to convert the string StackTrace in the exception to a more structured data object?

Or is there a method that can get me this information while I am catching the exception?
Maybe something using reflection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `StackTrace` class with constructor accepting `Exception`:

```
static void ShowExceptionStackTrace(Exception ex)
{
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace(ex, true);

    foreach (var frame in stackTrace.GetFrames())
        Console.WriteLine(frame.GetMethod().Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [System.Diagnostics.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class.  You can create the object and walk over the frames.

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
foreach (var frame in st.GetFrames())
{
    Console.WriteLine(frame.GetFileName().ToString()
        + ":"
        + frame.GetFileLineNumber().ToString());
}
```

Comment: This is a really handy class. If you ever want to determine what method called you, and if there are any custom attributes defined on that method then you need this class.

Comment: well i found out that u can pass an exception object to the contructor of StackTrace(). so bassicaly that is it :)

Comment: @Karim: that is the easier way :)

Comment: the problem is that i am sending this Exception object to a function that is handling the logging of the exception. so if i create a StackTrace() , it will give me the current stack trace and not the one associated with the exception

Comment: are you sure you are creating it from the exception? that seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, if you want a consistent solution you are out of luck.

You can get a hodge podge solution by storing the [stack trace on exception construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718458/why-does-stack-get-truncated-in-exception-stacktrace/1719449#1719449).

But, there are no hooks in the framework that are called when an exception is thrown.